# Button inside update panel is not working on INT Environment but works fine in Dev environment (both are in the same server)

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
```

I have integrated custom authentication on our application and every thing is working fine on my local machine and DEV environment (Windows 2012 Server with SSL Certificate without custom authentication (works only on INT Environment ) ).

the same code I have deployed on INT Environment (windows 2012 server with SSL Certificate with custom authentication ). Button inside update panel is not working. I tried with multiple scenario it's not working.

only the difference between DEV and INT is

1. Custom authentication (HttpModule - I tried commenting the module still facing the same issues)
2. rewrite rule in web.config ( tried commenting the code still facing the same issues)
3. DEV and INT Environment are in the Same Server (Windows 2012 R2)
4. its throwing error in ScriptResource.axd

Please suggest your input to fix the problems. Many thanks.

Comment: You should share your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I faced to this error few months ago when I migrate from IE 9 to IE
>   10.

It seems there is(are) an(some) incompatibility issue(s) between ASP.NET AJAX Client Library 4.x and IE 10.

I found changing compatibility settings of IE, would resolve my problem. I added following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

at top of my page as first line of html head section, before every other tags (as follow),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
...
```

PageRequestManagerParserErrorException never occurred again, but some IE10 specific CSS3 rules did not affect because of changed compatibility setting.

I recently wrote this situation to [Microsoft Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect) and they told they are investigating.

> This problem is related to ajax request cycle and the problem solution
>   is in webresources cache object is being treated by browser as
>   unhandled request.
>
> to resolve the problem the call trace must be captured using any web
>   resource monitor and it is always advised to have request with
>   timestamp or unique identifier.
>
> unmannaged ajax requests under browser shows this type of error
>   sometimes this also shows 500 error.

If you are modifying the HttpResponse state, it is necessary to move this "button" from the Telerik AjaxPanel/MS UpdatePanel.

See the [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException - what it is and how to avoid it](https://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it) blog post for more information.